# Unpack all arrays in a JSON column SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2019

Say I have a table `Schema.table` with these columns

```
id | json_col
```

on the forms e.g

```
id=1
json_col ={"names":["John","Peter"],"ages":["31","40"]}
```

The lengths of `names` and `ages` are always equal but might vary from id to id (size is at least 1 but no upper limit).

How do we get an "exploded" table - a table with a row for each "names", "ages" e.g

```
id | names | ages 
---+-------+------
 1 | John  | 31
 1 | Peter | 41
 2 | Jim   | 17
 3 | Foo   |  2
.
.
```

I have tried `OPENJSON` and CROSS APPLY but the following gives any combination of `names` and `ages` which is not correct, thus I need to to a lot of filtering afterwards

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Schema.table
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Schema.table,'$.names')
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Schema.table,'$.ages')
```

Comment: This format is really bad - bad relational and bad JSON. For starters, there should be a proper table to hold those records. Second, the JSON string should contain *one* array with objects containing name and age attributes

Comment: Why was this format used in the first place? There are probably better ways to solve the original problem without this format. SQL Server can already store data in columnar format for example but applications still see a regular table. The built-in columnstore indexes would achieve far better compression and query acceleration than JSON arrays

Comment: It is used to see a specific id-journey so to speak. The field-names etc. are not a correct replika of the real data set, which cannot be exposed.

Comment: You can provide a good example though. What you do right now is extremely slow and simply can't scale. You have to scan the entire table each time to parse the values and reconstruct records without benefit of indexing. If you wanted to have a large number of optional columns you could have used eg [sparse columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-ver15) and define 20K, 30K of optional columns

Comment: The data creation/update etc. is handled elsewhere, so that is not a concern. The answer from @Shnugo yield results in around 2 seconds, which is more than fine. Thanks for the concern though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggestion

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(id INT,json_col NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,N'{"names":["John","Peter"],"ages":["31","40"]}')
                      ,(2,N'{"names":["Jim"],"ages":["17"]}');

SELECT t.id
      ,B.[key] As ValueIndex
      ,B.[value] AS PersonNam
      ,JSON_VALUE(A.ages,CONCAT('$[',B.[key],']')) AS PersonAge
FROM @tbl t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.json_col) 
            WITH(names NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON
                ,ages  NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.names) B;
```

The idea in short:

- We use `OPENJSON` with a `WITH` clause to read `names` and `ages` into new json variables.
- We use one more `OPENJSON` to "explode" the names-array
- As the `key` is the value's position within the array, we can use `JSON_VALUE()` to read the corresponding age-value by its position.

One general remark: If this JSON is under your control, you should change this to an entity-centered approach (array of objects). Such a *position dependant* storage can be quite erronous... Try something like

```
{"persons":[{"name":"John","age":"31"},{"name":"Peter","age":"40"}]}
```

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer since it is around 40x times faster than @Barbaros Özhan and more read-able IMO

Comment: @CutePoison and a proper table would be 10000x faster.

Comment: Most likely, but that would be another question.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional Aggregation along with applying `CROSS APPLY` might be used :

```
SELECT id, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN RowKey = 'names' THEN value END) AS names,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RowKey = 'ages' THEN value END) AS ages
  FROM
  (
   SELECT id, Q0.[value] AS RowArray, Q0.[key] AS RowKey
     FROM tab
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonCol) AS Q0
  ) r
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(r.RowArray) v
 GROUP BY id, v.[key]   
 ORDER BY id, v.[key]

 id | names | ages 
 ---+-------+------
  1 | John  | 31
  1 | Peter | 41
  2 | Jim   | 17
  3 | Foo   |  2
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dcb6e7309ab4b3d61662bc546c9a5e43)</kbd>

*The first argument for `OPENJSON` would be a JSON column value, but not a table itself*